# How to specify Azure VM default port to use when entering URL without port number

Tags: ubuntu, azure, deployment, meteor, cname

So I've got a Meteor application deployed on a Azure VM (Ubuntu) that can be accessed via http://.cloudapp.net:3000/

I have a domain name and I want to create a CNAME record to point to my Azure VM.

The problem is CNAME doesn't let you specify a port, only a URL ( http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/ )

So I can't put in http://.cloudapp.net:3000/.

How can I tell my Azure VM that when I go to http://.cloudapp.net, it should automatically be port 3000 unless otherwise specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your meteor instance with the environmental variable `PORT=80` or (`meteor --port 80 --production`). Also It might be better if you didn't just use `meteor` to run your app. You would get more performance out if you bundled it with

```
meteor bundle app.tar.gz
```

Then unbundle this on your ubuntu server and follow the instructions in the `README` to get it running.

Comment: I went through the README and I seem to be able to boot up the node server but I can't seem to access it. I've definitely enabled 80 as an endpoint in azure though... is it possible to set the default port to not be 80?

Comment: Does it say `LISTENING`? By default there is no port (not too sure but it might go to 3000) until you give it one. Something like `PORT=80 MONGO_URL=<your mongodb url> ROOT_URL=http://yourdomain.com node main.js` should work

Comment: You can declare a Windows Azure endpoint with the public port being 80 and the private port being 3000: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/

Comment: Ahh ok. So is your app running it should say `LISTENING` if all is ok? So you're using the azure endpoint as a proxy to direct traffic from 80 to 3000? Have you specified port 3000 as an environmental variable though?

Comment: Hi, yeah it said LISTENING... i got it working, I used PORT=80 MONGO_URL=<your mongodb url> ROOT_URL=http://yourdomain.com node main.js but for port 80, I had to run it as sudo